# Singleton with multiserver

Tags: c#, singleton

I am using below code for Implementing singleton instance and store some data in it as a list and access across class files in project.
My question is what will happen if this project is hosted in two servers whether two instance will be created.
Because i think it will create two instance if it is from two servers,That is what i need even.

Code below
Two questions:

1. How many instance if same server and multiple web site?
2. How many instance if two different server?

   ```
   public class XXX
   {
      private static XXX _instance;
       // Lock synchronization object
       private static readonly object SyncLock = new object();

       private XXX()
       {
       }

       public static XXX Instance
       {
           get
           {
               if (_instance == null)
               {
                   lock (SyncLock)
                   {
                       if (_instance == null)
                       {
                           _instance = new XXX();
                       }
                   }
               }
               return _instance;
           }
       }

       public List<XXX> XXXDetails { get { return _XXX ; } set { _XXX  = value; } }
       private List<XXX> _XXX = new List<XXX>();
   }
   ```

Comment: 1 instance per application per server. 2 web applications = 2 instances.

Comment: thanks for your response. so if two web servers then two instance will be created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .NET, an application or service works in a *sandbox* called *application domain* represented by the `AppDomain` class.

That is, a static resource will be only available to the same `AppDomain` and won't be shared across processes.

In the other hand, if above statement wouldn't be true, about the question of *what happens in case of two servers*, do you really imagine two servers sharing memory and 2 processes accessing the same memory? Static members have never behaved this way in any language.

Comment: Two servers its acceptable it will have two instances .

Comment: Two servers its acceptable it will have two instances .For one server you mean like two application will have 2 app domain so it wont share across each other.But in case if two application under same server is configured for same app domain will it have two instance?